# How to change the DUID of DHCPv6 client with Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)

Tags: linux, dhcp, ipv6

I am using the ISC DHCPv6 client in the Linux environment. when I start the DHCPv6 client, by default it picks the link-layer address as an identifier.  In the Solicit packet, I could see the DUID type as a Link-layer address plus time.

I don't want to expose my MAC address. How to set up the DUID-UUID type as an identifier?

I could extract the UUID from the kernel file, but I am not sure how to make my DHCPv6 client use this as an identifier.

#cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
339fa401-2df6-48c4-ac04-ee7d228508c0

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in the `dhclient6.conf` solved it:

```
send dhcp6.client-id 00:04: <128 bit UUID in XX:XX:.. format >;
```